# Plesk Server hast 100% CPU Usage by Apache Issue found in one client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, plesk

I have an ubuntu V-Server with Plesk, and have a 100% CPU Usage. When I check with htop I have hundreds of apache processes running.

I tried to figure out from where those processes are comming. I found out I have two Domains which causes this issue. When I deaktivate those in Plesk my CPU usage goes down to 1%.

So I tried to check with tcpdump whats going on and reactivated it again.

In tcpdump I got thousands of these messages:

`IP plesk.mydomain.de.http > 104-200-24-39.ip.linodeusercontent.com.43142: Flags [.], seq 2896:5792, ack 1, win 118, options [nop,nop,TS val 198370388 ecr 813058895], length 2896: HTTP`

and

`IP 104-200-24-39.ip.linodeusercontent.com.43048 > plesk.mydomain.de.http: Flags [.], ack 27025, win 1318, options [nop,nop,TS val 813059605 ecr 198370270], length 0`

The IP and the port on this `104-200-24-39.ip.linodeusercontent.com.43142` is changing.

Any hints for me whats that and what I can do against this?

I tried to use fail2ban, but I only can block Ip adresses ... and the IP changes several times.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use fail2ban, but I only can block Ip adresses ...

This is not quite correct. Fail2ban is able to ban literally everything, not the IPs only.
 See [fail2ban :: wiki :: How to ban something other as host (IP address), like user or mail, etc.](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/How-to-ban-something-other-as-host-(IP-address),-like-user-or-mail,-etc.) for examples.
But I assume you wouldn't need it...

> and the IP changes several times.

Sure it does - nowadays the large botnets doing the bruteforce.
But if an IP found `maxretry` times during `findtime` seconds, this IP will be banned in fail2ban. Additionally `bantime.increment = true` may help here because it'd additionally reduce attempt count and prolong the ban-time for known as bad recidive IP, repeating the attack later (after unban).

Everything you need is to find a log file or journal where plesk logging failed attempts or the attacks, to write a `failregex` matching the failures and to create a jail monitoring this log.